# Ruby debugger: stepping into expressions entered on the prompt

Tags: ruby, debugging

Sometimes I am debugging some code, step over a line and think: "hmmm, I would like to have stepped into that". Or I enter some expression that is then evaluated (I always have 'autoeval' on) and think: "why does it give this result? I would like to step into this expression I just entered, to see exactly what it is doing".

As far as I have been able to find, this is not possible with the 1.8.7. `ruby-debug` nor with the 1.9.3 `debugger`. Is this there some other Ruby debugger that supports this?

Answer (score 2):

There is a rewrite of ruby-debug called [trepanning](https://github.com/rocky/rb-trepanning/wiki) which allows nested debugging via the "debug" command. See https://github.com/rocky/rb-trepanning/wiki/Nested-debugging.

Unfortunately it requires a patched MRI Ruby 1.9.3 (or 1.9.2) because the underlying problem is in the MRI 1.9 runtime system. See https://github.com/rocky/rb-trepanning/wiki/How-to-install-rb-trepanning for how to install.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can do all the things you asked for.
While in a debug-session do the following:

```
(rdb:1)s # steps into method
(rdb:1)l # list current line
(rdb:1)obj.method # eval expression
```

Although stepping into a just entered expression is not possible - as far as i know
Dirty:

```
(rdb:1)def someobj.some_method_name
(rdb:2)* debugger
(rdb:3)* my.expression_i_want_to_step_in
(rdb:4)* end
(rdb:5)someobj.some_method_name
(rdb:1) # this should be the new session at my.expression_i_want_to_step_in - untested
```

A quick [summary of ruby-debug](http://pivotallabs.com/users/chad/blog/articles/366-ruby-debug-in-30-seconds-we-don-t-need-no-stinkin-gui-)

Comment: "Although stepping into a just entered expression is not possible - as far as i know" -> unfortunately that is exactly the additional functionality I'm interested in.